# Replacing a union in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I’m trying to retrieve the number of unique users that have made a purchase in a monthly basis.  This sounds simple but the problem here is that we have three type of products and the purchases of these products are on different tables in which the only common key is the user_id, so in order to find out unique users I have to query the three tables separately, union the results and execute a count distinct.

Here’s an example of what I’m doing right now:

```
SELECT
    month,
    count(distinct user_id) as users
FROM
( 
SELECT  
    DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date,’%Y-%m) as month, 
    user_id 
FROM purchases_a

UNION

SELECT  
    DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date,’%Y-%m) as month, 
    user_id 
FROM purchases_b

UNION

SELECT  
    DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date,’%Y-%m) as month, 
    user_id 
FROM purchases_c
)
GROUP BY 1
```

Is this the only way to go?  This query takes forever. Thanks!

Comment: replace `UNION`s with `UNION ALL`s for more performance. Except that, your method is already fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question after [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info). We need more information about your tables and their indexes to help you. It's possible that covering indexes might help.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: Sounds like it was a mistake to build `a`, `b`, `c` instead of having a single table.

Comment: Please add EXPLAIN EXTENDED ahead of your query and share that as well. You should consider adding indices on the columns you are selecting and aggregating from.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `union all` in a subquery and then aggregate:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date, '%Y-%m') as month,
       count(distinct user_id)
from ((select user_id, purchase_date from purchases_a) union all
      (select user_id, purchase_date from purchases_b) union all
      (select user_id, purchase_date from purchases_c)
     ) p
group by month
```